# AWS EMR Spark Application Logging to CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-cloudwatch

It is not clear to me that

- *application logging* inside a Spark App itself, running on AWS EMR,

  - executed via spark-shell or Steps

    - will end up in CloudWatch Logs for reporting, if the CloudWatch Agent is installed on the EMR Cluster.

Will it or not?

Comment: this is still not answered, and I still don't know how to do it!